# Can I modify the Maven deploy phase to replace the maven-deploy-plugin with my own plugin?

Tags: maven, deployment, phase, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm pretty new to Maven...

What I'm trying to do is skip the maven-deploy-plugin during the deploy phase, while replacing it with my own plugin (i.e. I'm deploying to a non-repository location).

I realize I could do this in multiple other ways, but the boss wants to be able to run:

> mvn deploy

To get the results of my current workaround, which is disabling the maven-deploy-plugin (which seems to be disabling the entire deploy phase), and manually specifying the custom upload goal from the command line.

I'm currently failing to succeed in my mission with:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

in the build/plugins/plugin section containing my plugin specification, since the deploy phase is skipped by:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

> disabling the maven-deploy-plugin (which seems to be disabling the entire deploy phase)

This is not correct. Disabling `maven-deploy-plugin` doesn't disable the entire deploy phase. This is how it should be done (looks like you're doing it already):

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Hi, In case where I'd like to deploy-file instead of deploy, what should be the configuration?

Answer (score 9):

Try this (untested) alternative for disabling the standard deploy plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This will work until `maven-deploy-plugin` (in some future version) decides to bind itself to some other execution ID, different from `default-deploy`

Comment: This works and it is useful if you want to replace the standard deploy behavior with e.g. a specific deploy-file execution.

Comment: @yegor256 I agree. Although I would imagine that would be picked up quite quickly during a cautious move to a new version of Maven.

Comment: @JustinRowe But how can I define another deploy execution after I have disabled the deploy plugin?

Comment: Just add another execution that does what you want in the phase you want

Answer (score 1):

I want to build on @yegor256's answer a bit... 8 years, 4 months later!

I found myself here getting into the weeds on some legacy Maven configurations that were full of [cruft](http://catb.org/jargon/html/C/cruft.html). Coming from a Maven mindset, albeit some years between now and active hacking, I was re-familiarizing myself with the Maven lifecycle.

TLDR... `mvn help:effective-pom` is your friend. Use your IDE's tools for viewing the effective POM often (NetBeans makes it easy. I added a keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ.)

In the configuration I was reviewing, the previous developers had created two (2) `deploy-file` executions, one `war`, one `jar`.

```xml
<build>
...
  <plugins>
  ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>deploy-war</id>
          <phase>deploy</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            ... omitted ...
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>deploy-jar</id>
          <phase>deploy</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            ... omitted ...
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  ...
  </plugins>
...
</build>
```

I was aware that these executions would be appended to the `default-deploy` bound to the `deploy` phase and observed this behavior in the logs. The `default-deploy` would run, uploading an empty war file, then the `deploy-war` would run, uploading, and overwriting, the first war file.

Several options exist.

### `skip` and `combine.self="override"` (my preference)

As presented, using `<skip>` as a `<configuration>` option is viable. It is safe and more portable than setting setting the `<phase>` to `none`.

However, it will be inherited by the other executions (certainly as presented). To prevent this, [you must explicitly tell your additional `<execution>` configurations to not inherit](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#advanced_configuration_inheritance).

```xml
...
...
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>deploy-war</id>
          <phase>deploy</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration combine.self="override">
            ... omitted ...
          </configuration>
        </execution>
...
...
```

### Override `default-deploy`

Another option, possibly more verbose and lest esoteric than `combine.self="override"` is to [override the execution of the `default-deploy`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html) `<id>` of the plugin.

```xml
...
        <execution>
          <id>default-deploy</id>
          <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
...
```

This will not be inherited by the additional `<executions>`.

### Another option

As @yegor256 notes, but in the additional configurations explicitly state `<skip>false</skip>` to "reset" the inherited `<skip>` from the plugin.

HTH.